# GitHub error when I want to push some files on GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I need some help. I want to push some files on GitHub remote depository and I get this error:

```
flori@LAPTOP-DGOOOTH0 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/CURS/CodeFactory/F21-GIT-pairPartnerSurname-pairLeaderSurname (main)
$ git push -u origin main
****To https://github.com/AlinaAPP/F21-GIT-pairLeaderSurname-pairPartnerSurname-local.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/AlinaAPP/F21-GIT-pairLeaderSurname-pairPartnerSurname-local.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details**.**
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! have you tried to pull first? maybe there are some changes in remote(Github) repo that you don't have it yet.

Comment: Please read the error message, if it's unclear google/search for an explanation of what it means.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind